# IOS 7 link between Xcode and Xamarin not working correctly

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, ios7, xamarin-studio

I just started with a new project app. This app will support IOS 7 and I started to create the first View Controller in the new Xcode. When I run the app from Xamarin Studio(I'm on the beta channel) the app launches without any errors.

When the app is loaded on the simulator / on a device the UI is completely differed from the design in Xcode.

**Xcode:**

[image]

**IOS 7 Simulator / device:**
[image]

I have to note that this is the first time I'm using IOS 7 in combination with Xamarin Studio. I also noticed that if I create a push segue in Xcode on a button this will not work. It looks like the button is disabled in the simulator / on the device for some reason.

Comment: It's something to do with auto layout I Guess, check your auto layout settings for every view on the screen.

Comment: @rptwsthi I have checked this but auto layout is disable on all views.

Comment: That looks like the background color of your controller's view is set to black. Is there any code in your project that would be doing that?

Comment: @Greg Thats the weird part. I have not touched any code in Xamarin.

Comment: Tested it on a iPhone 4s with the same result. So there is something wrong with Xcode? I edit the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's caused by the View background color, and the alpha (transparency) property of the background and the light-blue parts.

So, in `XCode` `IB` check the background color (the one you set, or the one by default), put it to the value you like (say White), and **make sure the alpha is set to 1**

Comment: no, you can do it from within `xcode` `ib`. If it doesn't work, share your `.xib`

Comment: Im using a storyboard. Here is the file: https://mega.co.nz/#!0ZJTDTLa!ch3MRDrGAsVcrvYKGJ2e6hGSBQU3bmGEddafj3jSilU